# How to return default object in TypeScript if there are not others?

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
  return {
            ...defaultPathAttributes,
            ...(parentTreeNode?.pathAttributesSelection),
            ...(layerTreeNode?.pathAttributesSelection),
        };
```

Idea is this. If there is a layerTreeNode, take it. If not, take parentTreeNode. And if it is not there, return the default object.

Is it okay?

Comment: What specifically is the problem with your code? This is not a [mcve].

Comment: See my updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample code won't do exactly what you want.  Take the example below...

```
const default = { x: 1 };
const selectionA = { y: 2 };
const selectionB = { x: undefined, z: 3 };
return {
  ...default,
  ...selectionA,
  ...selectionB
};
```

If your intention is to have selectionB used instead of selectionA if it isn't null, then your objective will not be achieved.  The resulting object will be `{ x: undefined, y: 1, z: 3 }`.  So not only is the result the combination of all 3, but the default value for *x* is overwritten by *undefined* since it is present in *selectionB*.

If your intention is to just return he properties from which ever object isn't nullish in some predetermined order, then the null coalescing operator would be more appropriate.

```
return {
  ...(layerTreeNode?.pathAttributesSelection 
    ?? parentTreeNode?.pathAttributesSelection 
    ?? defaultPathAttributes)
};
```

Even the example above would not do *exactly* what you specified above.  If *layerTreeNode* wasn't nullish but the property *pathAttributesSelection* was, then it would go to the next variable.

If the above scenario isn't acceptable, then you'll need to use the conditional ternary or other conditional structure.

```
return {
  ...(layerTreeNode ? layerTreeNode.pathAttributesSelection
    : parentTreeNode ? parentTreeNode.pathAttributesSelection
    : defaultPathAttributes)
};
```

Bottom line, you need to be deliberate with what you want to achieve, as its not quite clear by your post.  Changes in logic will produce similar looking, but slightly different results.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `parseInt` in layerTreeNode.